# Не работают сконвертированные форматы шрифтов (.eot, .woff2, .woff .svg), кроме .ttf

Tags: css, шрифты

Подключал шрифты через свойство @font-face(практикуюсь). Скачал шрифт в формате .ttf, сконвертировал в другие форматы (.eot, .woff2, .woff .svg).

Конвертировал на таком сайте - https://anyconv.com/ru/

Подключил. Шрифт на странице отобразился и вроде бы всё норм, но когда полез в консоль наткнулся на такие ошибки:

- "Failed to decode downloaded font: [http://127.0.0.1:5500/fonts/raleway/Raleway-Regular.woff2"](http://127.0.0.1:5500/fonts/raleway/Raleway-Regular.woff2%22)
- "127.0.0.1/:1 OTS parsing error: invalid sfntVersion: -2147361775"

CSS свойство прописано верно, шрифт работает, но в консоли творится ересь. Решил разобраться, закомментировал остальные форматы, кроме .ttf - шрифт отоброжается, ошибок в консоли больше нет.

Такой вопрос - может ли конвертер шрифтов испортить сконвертированный шрифт? Пробовал другие конвертеры - ситуация такая же. Font2web по какой-то причине не работает выдаёт ошибку - "An unknown error occured, please try again later. This might also happen if the font cannot be converted at all." Почему-то не может преобразовать шрифт, пробовал через него прогонять другие шрифты - та же история. Шрифты брал с Google fonts.

Можете подсказать хороший конвертер?

Всем спасибо за ответы)))

Comment: У меня только один вопрос: зачем его конвертировать если он есть на [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Raleway) и его можно [просто скачать](https://gwfh.mranftl.com/fonts/raleway)?

Comment: Если же всё-таки надо, то самый известный и надёжный сайт https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: Дело в том, что я практикуюсь. Мне сейчас важно понять где сконвертировать, как подключить. вдруг у заказчика будет свой шрифт, которого нет на Google-fonts, вдруг он будет в ttf формате)

Comment: А вот fontssquirrel у меня почему-то удалил кириллицу из шрифта. То бишь на Русском не работал, только на Английском

Comment: Надо выбрать Exprert — No Subsetting или Custom Subsetting и выбрать нужные языки. По умолчанию там только латиница

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ. Вот этого не знал))